# Google AUTOML API integration issue using service account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl, appian

I am trying to integrate few of Google AUTOML API's to my system and I am always getting an error as "Service account credentials are invalid". I have tried creating multiple Private keys but none of them worked, I believe I have correctly followed the steps mentioned in - https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/tutorial#configure_your_project_environment
Can anyone support here to identify the possible root causes for this authenticaiton failure?

Comment: Finding solution for the same problem